# Getting string from JSON Android studio

Tags: android, json

so I'm having problem now. all I want to do is to get the value of the string inside the json file. so here is actually my code for the api.

```
 String accountnumber = account_no.getText().toString().trim();
    String accountname = account_name.getText().toString().trim();
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api-uat.unionbankph.com/uhac/sandbox/accounts/"+accountnumber)
            .get()
            .addHeader("x-ibm-client-id", "c6243a29-8d78-40ac-9940-5adce3f3cf15")
            .addHeader("x-ibm-client-secret", "*********************")
            .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

my question is actually what to do next to get the data from the api? from the test from the api this is the json result

```
[
{
    "account_no": "1xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "currency": "PHP",
    "account_name": "Richard Real",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "avaiable_balance": "100000.00",
    "current_balance": "100000.00"
}
]
```

Comment: I recommend you take a look at Retrofit, GSON, Jackson, OkHttp, RxJava

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, you need to learn.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

**Second** the code for parsing will be as.

```
JSONArray j_array = new JSONArray(response); // main array(root)
int len = j_array.length();
JSONObject obj_1;
for (int a = 0; a < len; a++) {
   obj_1 = j_array.getJSONObject(a); // Object on index a
   // get the data from Json Object like
   String account_no = obj_1.getString("account_no");
..... etc.
}
```

Comment: hi. when I tried running. i get an error Error:(92, 60) error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: hey, this one is now working actually. now my problem is how can I get the string then add a condition to check if the account number the user input is the same with the account_no in the json

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(yourreposnse);

for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.lenght;i++){
JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
String account_no = jsonobject.getString("account_no");
String currency = jsonobject.getString("currency");
String account_name = jsonobject.getString("account_name");
String status = jsonobject.getString("status");
String avaiable_balance= jsonobject.getString("avaiable_balance");
String current_balance= jsonobject.getString("current_balance");
}
```